# Error: This command is not available when running the Angular CLI outside a workspace While migrating legacy application

Tags: node.js, angular, docker, npm, node-modules

Working on a legacy angular application where I have to fix few vulnerabilities . Updated node image in docker file(Before update also) and seeing below issues. Not able to figure out what exactly the issue is

**Error**
[image]
**Docker File:**

[image]

package.json

---

[image]
I see some posts are saying that it could be the issue with versions compatibility but could not able to figure out exactly for which library we have compatibility issue

Does node image don't install appropriate npm version ? Do I need to install it manually ?

Comment: Don't post code (and errors) as images, post then as text

Answer (score 0):

Try to change work directory to something else. i face same issue with angular 15+, and node upgrade.